# Sending message to WM_PAINT

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to make a program for controlling the movement of a box with arrow key.I have a problem in my code.Is it possible to send a message through SendMessage to WM_PAINT to draw a new rectangle on pressing LEFT key?
Following is my code

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch(wParam)
    {
       case VK_LEFT:                              //LEFT MOVEMENT


    SendMessage(hwnd,WM_PAINT,VK_LEFT,0);
        break;



       case VK_ESCAPE: 
           //FOR ENDING THE GAME WITH ESCAPE KEY
           SendMessage(hwnd,WM_DESTROY,VK_ESCAPE,0);
        break;
    }


case WM_PAINT:
    hdc=BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);


      Rectangle(hdc,x,600,x1,700);
    if(wParam==VK_LEFT)
    { Rectangle(hdc,x-50,600,x1-50,700);

    }
    EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
    return 0;
case WM_DESTROY:

    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
}
where 

         x1=550;
          x=500
```

When left key is pressed then does the control goes to WM_PAINT

Because When I write

```
if(wParam==VK_LEFT)
        { Rectangle(hdc,x-50,600,x1-50,700);

        }
```

nothing happens but when I write

```
if(wParam==VK_ESCAPE)
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
```

The window exits with escape key
Its not the final code .I am just trying to understand that why `VK_LEFT` doesn't executes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never send `WM_PAINT`. The system is in charge of doing that. Instead, you call `InvalidateRect` specifying the rectangle that you wish to be re-painted. The system will mark that rectangle as invalid, and when the next paint cycle occurs, that rectangle will be re-painted.

If you want to invalidate more complicated regions there is `InvalidateRgn`.

If you just wish for the entire window to be invalidated, pass `NULL` to the `lpRect` parameter of `InvalidateRect`.

Comment: +1 This. Though you _could_ send `WM_PAINT`, it just won't work as one would expect (same for e.g. `WM_TIMER`).

Comment: Is it specifically for WM_PAINT ?

Comment: @Damon If you sent `WM_PAINT`, or even posted it, what would happen when the window proc that handled that message called `BeginPaint`?

Comment: @MsFreedom911 Everything that I say on the answer is specific to painting. I think you could do worse than to have a good read of Petzold's classic book *Programming Windows*.

Comment: To make repaint faster you can use UpdateWindow

Comment: @David .I am reading it sir.I was just trying to make my own program

Comment: @marcin_j That doesn't make the paint faster, just sooner. And it's unusual to ever want to do that. I'm disappointed that you suggested `UpdateWindow` without adding all the necessary provisos.

Comment: @MsFreedom911 Good for you. There's a good section on painting in that book.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I see no reason why it should not "work as usual", including sending `WM_ERASEBKGND` or `WM_NCPAINT` and giving you a DC, _except_ the `WM_PAINT` message you post yourself _is posted_ (so by definition it executes much earlier, before input messages and system paint) and it doesn't contain the complete, correct update region (how could it -- you don't know it). Which is why I'm saying it probably won't work as expected. Also, the system will still generate the "normal" `WM_PAINT` message later which might repaint some of the region again.

Comment: @Damon It doesn't work because the system has not setup the paint surface, so `BeginPaint` fails.