# BitBlt not updating WM_PAINT in Windows C++ API

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, sprite-sheet

I have the following function to draw a loaded bitmap to a window.

```
void OnPaint(HWND hwnd) {
    PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
    HDC             hdc;
    BITMAP          bitmap;
    HDC             hdcMem;
    HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;

    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bmp = mainBitmap;
    oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, mainBitmap);

    GetObject(bmp, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);

    x += 64;
    RECT rect;
    rect.left = x;
    rect.top = 0;
    rect.right = x+64;
    rect.bottom = 64;

    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(
        hdc,                    // Handle to a device context
        rect.right - rect.left, // Bitmap width
        rect.bottom - rect.top  // Bitmap height
    );

    BitBlt(
        hdc,                    // Destination rectangle context handle
        0,                      // Destination rectangle x-coordinate
        0,                      // Destination rectangle y-coordinate
        rect.right - rect.left, // Destination rectangle width
        rect.bottom - rect.top, // Destination rectangle height
        hdcMem,                 // A handle to the source device context
        rect.left,              // Source rectangle x-coordinate
        rect.top,               // Source rectangle y-coordinate
        SRCCOPY                 // Raster-operation code
    );

    SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
```

And I have the following image loaded into `HBITMAP mainBitmap`:

[image: Sprite]

The image is drawn when the window opens successfully, and I see the first icon in the sprite bitmap (yellow grapple hook), but my issue is, when I press `'C'` to re-paint the window, the image does not change to the next icon in the sprite image.

**Things I Know**

- On initialization, `x = 64;`
- Every time I press `'C'`, paint is called. (Confirmed in Visual
  Studio Debugger)
- x is incremented by 64 each time `OnPaint` is called.

Why is the graphic not changing?

---

Here is my `WindowsProc` function to handle the `WM_PAINT` message:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_PAINT, OnPaint);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you handle the `WM_PAINT` message.

Comment: What are you doing when 'c' is pressed?

Comment: @Ron I've made an edit showing how I handle WM_PAINT

Comment: @JonathanPotter `SendMessage(m_hwnd, WM_PAINT, 0, 0);` - I can confirm this does indeed call my OnPaint function.

Comment: `WM_PAINT` is generated by the system when your window needs painting - you never send it yourself. Instead, use `InvalidateRect` to mark your window for repainting.

Comment: Never send the `WM_PAINT` message. Read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365802/sending-message-to-wm-paint).

Comment: @JonathanPotter @MichaelWalz Thank you guys, solved! `InvalidateRect` was my answer

Comment: You shouldn't increment `x` in `OnPaint()` as you have no control over when `OnPaint()` will be called by the system (try to move the window out of the screen and back in and see what happens). The right way to do this is to increment `x` in your `OnKeyDown()` handler before calling `InvalidateRect()`. This way `OnPaint()` will be stateless and produces a consistent result everytime it is called.

Comment: @zett42 yep, I was just using it as a test to see if it will change. That wasn't my final method, just a test.

Comment: *CreateCompatibleDC* + *CreateCompatibleBitmap* on every *WP_PAINT* bad design. this need do only once or when window resized

Comment: @RbMm This is not a good design either as it wastes a lot of memory if you have many controls. Also if controls are resizable, you have to reallocate buffer continually during resizing. I suggest to use the [buffered paint API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773257(v=vs.85).aspx) which retrieves buffer from cache.

Comment: @zett42 - reallocate DC may need or not need on resize - depend from what and how need paint. anyway `OnPaint` call on resize too and can on other case - so we can serious decrement *CreateCompatibleDC* + *CreateCompatibleBitmap* call count, if not need recreate DC on resize. about memory - but `BeginBufferedPaint` also create and return *DC*. you think that this *DC* (with bitmap in it) take less memory that created by *CreateCompatibleDC* ?

Comment: @RbMm Okay, my window is literally just a single icon as a splash screen that has no interaction with the user. If I place `CreateCompatibleDC` and `CreateCompatibleBitmap` in my `WM_CREATE` case, how will I get the hdc (which is usually taken from `BeginPaint()`)?

Comment: @Acidic - you need associate some class/struct with your window, and in this class have say `m_hMemDC` member. you create it on `WM_CREATE` , destroy on `WM_DESTROY` and use on `WM_PAINT`. the hdc for you window - simply get by `GetDC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call [function InvalidateRect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to update region.

Comment: `InvalidateRect` does not update a region. As the name implies, it invalidates a rectangular area, marking it dirty to be rendered the next time the system generates a `WM_PAINT` message.

Comment: @IInspectable so what do you suggest? `InvalidateRect()` allows you to parse `0` as the rect size, thus rendering the entire window.

Comment: I would suggest to rephrase this answer, to include an important detail: `InvalidateRect` does not perform any rendering. It merely marks an area that needs to be repainted, at some point in the future.

Comment: @IInspectable it worked perfectly fine for me, I don't think anything needs to be changed in my opinion.

Comment: @Acidic: Do you understand, *why* it works, too? Probably not, and this answer doesn't help much in explaining an important concept. I'm not claiming, that the solution is wrong. It isn't. But the explanation is.

Comment: @IInspectable Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?